# Is there a way to deploy a flask application which contains several tensorflow models onto pythonanywhere web platform?

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, wsgi, pythonanywhere

I have a Flask application that can take in a set of hyperparameters through an HTML form and release results in a tabular form. This application works on the local builtin Flask server, but I know what to deploy this app to the world wide web. I have tried everything from Heroku to google app engine, but pythonanywhere was the only one showing any sort of progress. Unfortunately, although I was able to "deploy" the application, I was immediately faced with an error message at rajeevdatta.pythonanywhere.com and the following in my error logs:

```
2019-11-23 22:08:50,543: Error running WSGI application
2019-11-23 22:08:50,547: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
2019-11-23 22:08:50,547:   File "/var/www/rajeevdatta_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-11-23 22:08:50,548:     from main import app as application  # noqa
2019-11-23 22:08:50,548: ***************************************************
2019-11-23 22:08:50,548: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2019-11-23 22:08:50,548: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2019-11-23 22:08:50,549: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2019-11-23 22:08:50,549: ***************************************************
2019-11-23 22:09:18,423: Error running WSGI application
2019-11-23 22:09:18,424: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
2019-11-23 22:09:18,424:   File "/var/www/rajeevdatta_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-11-23 22:09:18,424:     from main import app as application  # noqa
2019-11-23 22:09:18,424: ***************************************************
2019-11-23 22:09:18,425: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2019-11-23 22:09:18,425: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2019-11-23 22:09:18,425: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2019-11-23 22:09:18,425: ***************************************************
2019-11-23 22:09:22,868: Error running WSGI application
2019-11-23 22:09:22,868: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
2019-11-23 22:09:22,869:   File "/var/www/rajeevdatta_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-11-23 22:09:22,869:     from main import app as application  # noqa
2019-11-23 22:09:22,869: ***************************************************
2019-11-23 22:09:22,869: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2019-11-23 22:09:22,869: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2019-11-23 22:09:22,870: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2019-11-23 22:09:22,870: ***************************************************
2019-11-23 22:13:37,158: Error running WSGI application
2019-11-23 22:13:37,163: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
2019-11-23 22:13:37,163:   File "/var/www/rajeevdatta_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-11-23 22:13:37,164:     from main import app as application  # noqa
2019-11-23 22:13:37,164: 
2019-11-23 22:13:37,164:   File "/home/rajeevdatta/Downloads/archive_datta/main.py", line 11, in <module>
2019-11-23 22:13:37,164:     import tensorflow as tf
2019-11-23 22:13:37,165: ***************************************************
2019-11-23 22:13:37,165: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2019-11-23 22:13:37,165: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2019-11-23 22:13:37,165: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2019-11-23 22:13:37,166: ***************************************************
```

I tried to fix this issue by directly contacting pythonanywhere. I got the two emails below in response from Glen Jones.

> I think the problem here is that you're using a virtualenv -- if you
>   use one, everything that your app depends on has to be installed into
>   it.  If you don't use a virtualenv, then you'll have access to all of
>   the system-wide installed packages, including tensorflow.
>
> However, I've just spotted that you're using Tensorflow in a website's
>   code.  Unfortunately that doesn't work right now because of the way it
>   handles threads -- so even if you were able to fix the import problem,
>   it wouldn't work.

And:

> You can move the tensorflow stuff out of the web app and into a
>   scheduled task or an always on task. See
>   http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AsyncInWebApps/ for more details.

After receiving this information, I tried following his advice and found it quite difficult due to the vague nature of the information presented at the URL above. So, I plan to share as much information about this problem as possible in hopes of finding the solution.

Here is some relevant code from the main app Python script:

```
 from flask import Flask, request, render_template
 import tensorflow as tf
 from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
 from six.moves import range

 mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)


 app = Flask(__name__)
 # @ signifies a decorator - way to wrap a function and modifying its behavior

 @app.route('/')

 def homepage():
      return render_template("main.html")

 @app.route('/ConvNet')

 def ConvNet():
      return render_template("ConvNet.html")

 @app.route('/ConvNetForm', methods=["POST"])

 def ConvNetForm():

      #####

      return render_template("ConvNetForm.html", ConvResult=ConvResult,        test_accuracy=test_accuracy)


 @app.route('/MultiPerceptron')
 def MultiPerceptron():
      return render_template("MultiPerceptron.html")

 @app.route('/MultiPerceptronForm', methods=["POST"])
 def MultiPerceptronForm():

     #####

     return render_template('MultiPerceptronForm.html', MultiPerceptResult=MultiPerceptResult)

 @app.route('/RNN')
 def RNN():
     return render_template("RNN.html")

 @app.route('/RNNForm', methods=["POST"])
 def RNNForm():

     #####

 @app.route('/post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

 def post():
     if request.method == 'POST':
         return "You are using POST"
     else:
         return "You are probably using GET"

#added use_reloader=False to the code on August 18th 2019
if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, threaded=True)
```

I understand this is a unique problem that may require a tricky solution.

Comment: have you tried moving the tensorflow work moving into separate task processors like celery?

Comment: I only have a free pythonanywhere account. So, I do not think I would be able to set up a separate task for processing tensorflow work. If you can think of some way to do this on the free account, I would love to hear it. I really need to get this app deployed ASAP.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this (and deadlines) to your questions.